# Figuring out the percentage of A in relation to B

Tags: arithmetic

I have two numbers

`13.49`  and  `7.8`

I want to know how to figure out how much `7.8` is of `13.49` in percentage

e.g. `7.8` is 80% of `13.49`

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percentage is $\frac {7.8}{13.49}\cdot 100 \%\approx 57.82 \%$  Note that multiplying by $100 \%$ is multiplying by $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The word "percent" is derived from the Latin *per centum*, which means roughly "by the hundred". The upshot is that "$X$ percent" means "$X$ out of one hundred", or numerically, $\frac X {100}$.

In general, if we say something like "$Y$ is (some fraction) of $Z$", what we mean is that $Y$ is (equal to) that fraction **times** $Z$. Consider some examples: What is $\frac23$ of $9$? What is $\frac23$ times $9$?

In the context of percentages, it's the same idea, only our fraction will have denominator $100$. For your example, we have that $7.8$ is $X$ percent of $13.49$, where $X$ is some number that we're trying to figure out. Remember, that translates mathematically to $$7.8=\frac{X}{100}\cdot 13.49,$$ so multiplying both sides by $100$ gives us $$780=13.49X,$$ and dividing by $13.49$ gives us $$X=\frac{780}{13.49}\approx 57.82.$$ Therefore, "$7.8$ is $X$ percent of $13.49$" translates to "$7.8$ is approximately $57.82$ percent of $13.49$", or (if we want it to be exact and don't want decimals in our fractions) to "7.8 is $\frac{78000}{1349}$ percent of $13.49$".

Answer (score 1):

7.8 is not 80% of 13.49.

Given a number $A$ and a number $B$. $A$ is

$(100)(\frac{A}{B})$%

of $B$.

Comment: It was an example, if I knew what I was doing I probably wouldn't be asking this question

Comment: @mk_89: You could have used a variable, as in "$7.8$ is $p\%$ of $13.49$". That way you'd have made clear what you mean without making a wrong statement.